# How to regex the strings in an url

Tags: ruby, regex

```
http://something.com/bOhxBeD,SyhyTGi,TMDDSIB,U72gx2J,kQTIRy9,7VXgGDw,eSxIcK6,S5oNlnn,WBHHsLk,BdMGd2d,U9kNlsF,cHVyc7Y,D83kaJ5,cLWgdSO,iWtCIF3,ount8L6
```

I have tried to get the value: bOhxBeD, SyhyTGi and so on. This is what I come up with ( yes fairly simple ) `/([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})/`, it seems to work with PCRE:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/esPfN9vjNj1fZYoo)

But when it comes to Ruby, I use it like this :

```
str.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})/)
#<MatchData "bOhxBeD" 1:"bOhxBeD">
```

it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point out what's wrong with this regex ? Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but this may be better suited to methods other than regexes.  eg: require 'uri'; URI(str).path[1..-1].split(',')

Comment: @TimPeters this is a good answer too, thanks. But somehow to me when I look at this kind of thing, I think about regex anyway. So I try hard to learn it properly. But still, nice solution there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add word boundary `\b` inorder to match an exact 7 alphanumeric characters.

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yR1qN5/1)

```
irb(main):006:0> "http://something.com/bOhxBeD,SyhyTGi,TMDDSIB,U72gx2J,kQTIRy9,7VXgGDw,eSxIcK6,S5oNlnn,WBHHsLk,BdMGd2d,U9kNlsF,cHVyc7Y,D83kaJ5,cLWgdSO,iWtCIF3,ount8L6".scan(/\b([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})\b/)
=> [["bOhxBeD"], ["SyhyTGi"], ["TMDDSIB"], ["U72gx2J"], ["kQTIRy9"], ["7VXgGDw"], ["eSxIcK6"], ["S5oNlnn"], ["WBHHsLk"], ["BdMGd2d"], ["U9kNlsF"], ["cHVyc7Y"], ["D83kaJ5"], ["cLWgdSO"], ["iWtCIF3"], ["ount8L6"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 (?!.*?\/)[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}
```

Is should be this.Or else it will pick 7 letter words from link as well."somethi" will be in ans.But i guess that is not required.

Comment: it uses a negative lookahead i.e ?!.So anything which matches negative lookahead cannot be matched by the main matcher.So negative lookahead says match anything upto last /.So the ans can now come from raminign string only.That is what was required.

Answer (score 2):

`match` only picks up the first match.
You can try the global version of `match` which is `scan`.
You can use `scan` to search string not containing specific characters using `[^...]`:

```
str.scan(/[^\/\.\,]+/)[3..-1]   
#=> ["bOhxBeD", "SyhyTGi", "TMDDSIB", "U72gx2J", "kQTIRy9", "7VXgGDw", "eSxIcK6", "S5oNlnn", "WBHHsLk", "BdMGd2d", "U9kNlsF", "cHVyc7Y", "D83kaJ5", "cLWgdSO", "iWtCIF3", "ount8L6"]
```

Update:
If you know that the strings between the comma are always 7 characters, you can use this instead:

```
   str.scan(/[^\/\.\,]{7}/)[1..-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

it happens because your regexp match just one element which contain 7 chars, nothing more,
as simple solution could be:

```
str.match(/\/(.*)\z/)[1].split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split):

```
str[/.*\/(.*)/,1].split(',')
  #=> ["bOhxBeD", "SyhyTGi", "TMDDSIB", "U72gx2J", "kQTIRy9", "7VXgGDw",
  #    "eSxIcK6", "S5oNlnn", "WBHHsLk", "BdMGd2d", "U9kNlsF", "cHVyc7Y",
  #    "D83kaJ5", "cLWgdSO", "iWtCIF3", "ount8L6"]
```

`.*\/` in the regex, "greedy" as it is, will consume characters up to and including the last forward slash in the string.  Capture group #1 `(.*)` sucks up the remainder of the string and, due to the presence of `,1`, returns it. `split(',')` then breaks up the string to give you the desired array.

Another way:

```
str[str[/.*\//].size..-1].split(',')
```